# ¿Por qué inserta 0000-00-00 en un date con NOT NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un campo de tipo `date` con la restricción `NOT NULL`. Si ejecuto un `INSERT` sin especificar una fecha, me almacena el valor `0000-00-00` en ese campo.

¿Por qué inserta `0000-00-00` a pesar de tener `NOT NULL`? ¿Cómo puedo hacerle para que no me ejecute el `INSERT` y me mande un error?

Comment: que es lo que necesitas? que si la fecha es '0000-00-00' no te deje hacer el insert?

Comment: sería ideal que también muestres tu avance es decir el código que haz estado probando

Comment: ademas que te inserte 0000-00-00 no es un error ya que ese es el valor que por defecto se ponen en los campos de tipo date, null lo unico que va a hacer es no dejar que dejes ese campo vacio es decir sin asignarle valor

Comment: Revisa que en el atributo `Predeterminado` tenga `Ninguno`

Answer (score 5):

Podrías checar en tu servidor mysql lo siguiente

`show VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';`

o

`SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode global, @@SESSION.sql_mode session`

Debería mostrar un resultado que contenga lo siguiente

`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE`

para poder mostrar un error en caso que quieras realizar un insert con el campo fecha a `null` o `'0000-00-00'`, si no está habilitado, puedes habilitarlo añadiendo a la cadena esos modos, de la siguiente manera

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '...,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE';
SET SESSION sql_mode = '...,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE';
```

La documentación indica que si `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` está desactivada la insercción no marcara ningún `warning`, si está activa marcara un `warning`, si está activada con el modo estricto marcara un error a menos que se coloque `INSERT IGNORE` o `UPDATE IGNORE` lo cual realizara la insercción `'0000-00-00'` y marcara un warning.

```
mysql> show VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';

+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                                                                                                                     |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sql_mode      | ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode global, @@SESSION.sql_mode session\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
 global: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
session: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> create table fechas(fecha DATE NOT NULL);
mysql> insert into fechas values(0);
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '0' for column 'fecha' at row 1
mysql> insert into fechas values('0000-00-00');
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00' for column 'fecha' at row 1
```

[Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_in_date)